# onBlur property in react-rte react component

Tags: reactjs, rte

I am using react-rte as rich text editor in my react application. I went through the following link about the same https://github.com/sstur/react-rte

I couldn't find the `onBlur` property in this document. It would be a great help if someone could tell whether there is `onBlur` property in react-rte

Answer (score 4):

I had to go through the `react-rte -> dist -> react-rte.js` file to find the properties of this component. And there is onBlur property. Actually there are many properties like `onBlur, onFocus, onMouseDown, onEscape, onTab` etc. which are not mentioned in the given document of react-rte